# Post form using background Sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

In a PWA, how can I make the application schedule form POST submissions so that associated API requests get flushed as soon as the internet connection is back again?
Is it possible using background sync? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for posterity's sake...

It's easier to break the question into the key parts:

> how can I make the application schedule form POST submissions...

The standard cache.put() mechanism [does not support POST submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272243/9472324). The service worker can trap all communications with the server, including POST submissions, but then you have to save it to [the IndexedDB object store](https://serviceworke.rs/request-deferrer.html) manually, or use a library [like Workbox that will do that for you](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.backgroundSync.Queue.html).

> ...as soon as the internet connection is back again

There is a fair amount of latency with the Background Sync api, usually on the order of minutes.  [According to Google](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync): "Browsers that support the BackgroundSync API will automatically replay failed requests on your behalf **at an interval managed by the browser**, likely using **exponential backoff** between replay attempts."  Needless to say, the messages will *not* be sent immediately upon connecting to the internet.

> Is it possible using background sync? If yes then how?

If one can tolerate the above restrictions, then Service Workers can do the trick, but there is a pretty big learning curve.  It might be easiest to use a library like Workbox (with the [workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync#basic_usage)).