# How can I combine Firebase Callables with PWA offline functionality?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, progressive-web-apps

Since the Service Worker handles https requests when the application is offline my expectation is that the same behavior should be applied when using Firebase Callables functions. These Callables are basically just http - POST calls.

Setting:

- Angular 8 Frontend
- @angular/fire package as wrapper for firebase SDK
- @angular/pwa for offline capabilities
- firebase http callables functions on backend side to deal with requests 
  comming from frontend

Situation:

As user I trigger an action on the frontend which will perform a request to a firebase callable function. The callable function will send me back a response with information about success or failure which will be presented to me on the UI. 
This is working 100% as expected.
Now I will do the same process with my device offline.

My expectation:

Since my application is a PWA, the request should be intercepted by the service worker. The result status of the request should be 200.
When my device is getting back online the service worker should send the original request.

Current behavior:

When calling the firebase function in offline mode, the frontend (angular service) immediately returns status code 500 "internal error". When getting back online the Service Worker is not sending the past request to the callable function on firebase.

Is my expectation right?
Do I have to configure something on firebase side/ angular side?
Is this because of using @angular/fire as a wrapper?

Do you have any experience with such use cases and can provide further information?

Many thanks in advance!

```js
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

constructor(
    private readonly functions: AngularFireFunctions
}

doSomething(data:{text:string}){
  return this.functions.httpsCallable('handleEvent')({
        ... some data to pass to the function here ...
  });
}
```

When calling "doSomething" while the browser is offline a Response with status code 500 - internal - is passed back.

Calling the function when in online mode is working as expected.

Comment: After some Investigation I could find Out that the Problem is caused by Service worker. The Service worker does Not Support Post and pu
t methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101130/angular-service-worker-with-post-request