# How to I manage messages of chat application when the application is offline

Tags: node.js, angular

We are developing application for chatting.But when I am sending messages and if internet connectivity is gone how will I be able to send the messages like what's app do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a message broker software like RabbitMQ (https://www.rabbitmq.com) to handle these kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Off course, you can't really send messages offline, so what applications do is:

- buffering/storing "sent" messages if there is no network available
- check/await for network connection to be reestablished
- Actually send messages when application reconnects

For achieving this, if you're looking mainly on chat, you can use some library/package/software (as for example RabbitMQ mentioned on @Badis Merabet answer).

If there is no prebuilt solution available for your use case or you want to develop you own solution, you may use PWAs. Here are some links:

[General information on PWAs](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)

[Angular PWA docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)

You may also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272243/6481438) for more information. The last link have a cookbook on an approach to implement it.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.