# Request method 'POST' is unsupported

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

The following config throws an error of 'Request method 'POST' is unsupported'. I already read that the storage api does not request objects with a method of POST as keys in a cache, but I have no clue how to add a route, which manifests a networkOnly strategy for those requests.

Specs (setup taken from https://github.com/nystudio107/annotated-webpack-4-config)

- Using GenerateSW

webpack.settings.js (remember the importScripts statement)

```
workboxConfig: {
    swDest: "../sw.js",
    precacheManifestFilename: "js/precache-manifest.[manifestHash].js",
    importScripts: [
        "/dist/workbox-catch-handler.js"
    ],
    exclude: [
        /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)$/i,
        /\.map$/,
        /^manifest.*\\.js(?:on)?$/,
    ],
    globDirectory: "./web/",
    globPatterns: [
        "offline.html",
        "offline.svg"
    ],
    offlineGoogleAnalytics: true,
    runtimeCaching: [
        {
            urlPattern: /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|webp)$/,
            handler: "cacheFirst",
            options: {
                cacheName: "images",
                expiration: {
                    maxEntries: 20
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

wepack.prod.js

```
// webpack.prod.js - production builds
    const LEGACY_CONFIG = 'legacy';
    const MODERN_CONFIG = 'modern';
    const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

// config files
    const settings = require('./webpack.settings.js');
    const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
    ...

// Configure Workbox service worker
      const configureWorkbox = () => {
         let config = settings.workboxConfig;

         return config;
      };

// Module Exports – simplified for clarity - see github repro for more details
   module.exports = [
      ...
      ...,
    merge(
       common.modernConfig,
       {
          ...
          ...
          plugins: [
             ...
             new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW(
                configureWorkbox()
             ),
          ]
       }
   ]
```

workbox-catch-handler.js

```
// fallback URLs
   const FALLBACK_HTML_URL = '/offline.html';
   const FALLBACK_IMAGE_URL = '/offline.svg';

// This "catch" handler is triggered when any of the other routes fail to
// generate a response.

   workbox.routing.setCatchHandler(({event, request, url}) => {
      // Use event, request, and url to figure out how to respond.
      // One approach would be to use request.destination, see
      // https://medium.com/dev-channel/service-worker-caching-strategies-based-on-request-types-57411dd7652c

         switch (request.destination) {
            case 'document':
               return caches.match(FALLBACK_HTML_URL);
               break;

            case 'image':
               return caches.match(FALLBACK_IMAGE_URL);
               break;

            default:
               // If we don't have a fallback, just return an error response.
               return Response.error();
         }
   });

// Use a stale-while-revalidate strategy for all other requests.
      workbox.routing.setDefaultHandler(
         workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate()
      );
```

The error is caused by the strategy of the DefaultHandler, so I tried to add another route for those requests right below the DefaultHandler with no success. Eg:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
   new RegExp('*/admin/*'),
   workbox.strategies.networkOnly()
);
```

I also tried the bgSyncPlugin with no success. Any help is appreciated. I'd like to implement a side wide networkOnly strategy for POST requests (not only for admin URLS).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can service workers cache POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270702/can-service-workers-cache-post-requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cache POST requests with the Cache API, meaning you can't use a network first strategy.

See: [Can service workers cache POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270702/can-service-workers-cache-post-requests)

You might be able to do something with a network request (i.e. change the request type in the service worker by reading a POST response and generating a new response to put in the Cache API). This will require a custom strategy.

To access POST requests with the Workbox router, see: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#defining_a_route_for_non-get_requests

To write your own function to handle a network request see: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#matching_and_handling_in_routes

You might be able to re-use some of the workbox strategies, check here for details no how that might work: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#make-requests