# Offline POSTs with Progressive Web Apps in angular- post calls are not working in offline

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

Offline POSTs with Progressive Web Apps in angular- post calls are not working in offline.

how to success POST request

[post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njRdS.png)

How post calls are working in offline pwa?

..

please Explain how to do pwa for post requests. Can i have any workaround to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can service workers cache POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270702/can-service-workers-cache-post-requests)